# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(optional binding)

Tags: xcode, swift, option-type

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class HomePageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate   {

@IBOutlet weak var homPageTableView: UITableView!
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
var imageText = [String]()



override func   viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // DO any additional setup after loading the view
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (posts : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            //success fetxhing objects
            println(posts?.count)
            for post in posts! {

                self.imageFiles.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile) ---------error here
                 self.imageText.append(post["imageText"] as! String)
            }

            println(self.imageFiles.count)


        }else{             println(error)
    }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

As a title, It is keep saying "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at the line I draw.

There are a lot of questions about this, it is hard to read code for me, And even if I undertood, mine didn't go right.

where should I use optional binding?

And can u explain it with really easy example what is optional binding?

Thank you

Comment: upload! actually, that was parse data base problem. after I delete all my objects, it works fine Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `post` dictionary does not contain an `imageFile` key. When you access a dictionary using `post["imageFile"]` the result is the value (if the key exists) and `nil` (if the key does not exist). You can distinguish between these cases using

```
if let imageFile = post["imageFile"],
   let imageText = post["imageText"] {
     self.imageFiles.append(imageFile as! PFFile)
     self.imageText.append(imageText as! String)
} else {
     print("imageFile and/or imageText missing from \(post)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap your posts before looping through them because `posts: [AnyObject]?` is optional.

```
if error == nil {
    if let postData = posts{
        //success fetxhing objects
        println(postData?.count)
        for post in postData! {
            self.imageFiles.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
            self.imageText.append(post["imageText"] as! String)
        }
        println(self.imageFiles.count)
    }
}else{            
    println(error)
}
```

Comment: It's the `post["imageFile"]` force unwrap that is causing the problem. Had it been `posts` that was nil, the error would have occurred sooner.